# how to avoid endless animation triggered by multiple clicks on menu item

Tags: jquery

I am working on my second site where I decided to utilize jquery. I got a problem and can't resolve it and neither find out the solution on web.

So, I created one page site which has a menu and each item of it triggers certain animation (horizontal movement + fadeOut). By clicking on the second/third or fifth link, all initial home page animations are fading out, while clicking on "Home", all animations/images/etc. are returning to their proper-initial places. Though, if I click on the "Home" twice or ten times, on each click, all horizontally animated stuff are moving endless by the assigned distances.

So, my questions are: 1. how should I resolve this problem - endless animation by multiple clicks on "home" menu item; 2. how to make other menu items work properly and to find all animated objects back in the initial places by clicking on "home"?

Here is my code. Sorry if you find a mess here - I am really green in jquery. thank you in advance :)

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="nav">
       <li id="home"><a class="active" href="#">home</a></li>
       <li id="stylist"><a href="#">hair stylist</a></li>
       <li id="salon"><a href="#">salon</a></li>
       <li id="center"><a href="#">dibi center</a></li>
       <li id="gallery"><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
       <li id="press"><a href="#">press</a></li>
       <li id="check"><a href="#">check up</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>

 $(document).ready(function() {
     var nav_0 = $("li#home")
     var nav_1 = $("li#stylist")
     var rot1 = $("#rotate_1")
     var rot2 = $("#rotate_2")
     var rot3 = $("#rotate_3")
     var rot4 = $("#rotate_4")
     var rot5 = $("#rotate_5")
     var initialPage = $("#fade")

 nav_0.click(function(){
     initialPage.fadeIn(1500);
     rot1.animate({"left": "-=20%", "opacity": "1"}, 1000);
     rot2.animate({"top": "-=400px", "opacity": "1"}, 1000);
     rot4.fadeIn(2000);
     rot5.animate({"left": "+=200px", "opacity": "1"}, 1000);
     rot3.animate({"top": "+=300px", "opacity": "1"}, 1000);
 });

 nav_1.click(function(){
     initialPage.fadeOut(2000);
     rot1.animate({"left": "+=20%", "opacity": "0"}, 1500);
 rot2.animate({"top": "+=400px", "opacity": "0"}, 1500);
 rot4.fadeOut(800);
 rot5.animate({"left": "-=200px", "opacity": "0"}, 1500);
 rot3.animate({"top": "-=300px", "opacity": "0"}, 1500);
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

How about checking to see if the menu is already animating:

```
if($('.menuClass:animated').length == 0){
  *do the animation . . .*
}
```

This will check to see of '.menuClass' is animated, if it isn't, it will kick off an animation. If it is animated, it will do nothing.